# High Performance Audio Cracking / Prevent a CPU core from downclocking

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

This may be very specific, still trying to ask:

I'm founder of Heat Synthesizer, a software music synthesizer for Android. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nilsschneider.heat.demo)

This app generates audio signals in realtime and needs to do heavy math calculations to do so.

Having seen the talk on Google I/O 2013 about "High Performance Audio on Android" (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3kfEeMZ65c), I was excited to implement it as they suggested, but I keep having problems with crackling.

I have a CPU usage of a single core of about 50% on a Nexus 7 (2012), everything seems to be okay so far. Locking has been reduced to a minimum and most of the code is done lock-free.

Using an app that is called Usemon, I can see that the core I use for processing is used only 50% and is even being downclocked by the kernel because my CPU usage is not high enough.

However, this core speed changes result in crackling of the audio, because the next audio block is not calculated fast enough because my core is underclocked.

Is there any way to prevent a core from changing it's clock frequency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, I recommend the use of systrace ([docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html), [explanation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html), [example](http://bigflake.com/systrace/)) for this sort of analysis.  On a rooted device you can enable the "freq" tags, which show the clock frequencies of various components.  Works best on Android 4.3 and later.

The hackish battery-unfriendly way to deal with this is to start up a second thread that does nothing but spin while your computations are in progress.  In theory this shouldn't work (since you're spinning on a different core), but in practice it usually gets the job done.  Make sure you verify that the device has multiple cores (`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` or NDK equivalent), as doing this on a single-core device would be bad.

Assuming your computations are performed asynchronously in a separate thread, you can do a bit better by changing the worker thread from a "compute, then wait for work" to a "compute, then poll for work" model.  Again, far less efficient battery-wise, but if you never sleep then the kernel will assume you're working hard and needs to keep the core at full speed.  Make sure you drop out of polling mode if there isn't any actual work to do (i.e. you hit the end of input).