# Android thread performance/priority on Galaxy Note 2 when screen is touched/released

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I have an OpenGL game for Android. It runs at a good 60fps when the screen is touched. When I release my finger it goes back down to around 30fps. Does the touch event/release raise/lower a thread's priority and if so how can I replicate this to keep it at a constant 60fps. This only seems to be an issue on Galaxy Note 2 so far.

Comment: 30fps it's not bad result. Human can see 24 frames per second:)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using `onDrawFrame` and `setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY)`.

30 and 60FPS indicates that your implementation of `onDrawFrame` is called as the device's screen refreshes. Most displays refresh at 60Hz, giving you 60FPS.

It is likely that the Galaxy Note 2 has some power saving feature that limits screen refresh to 30Hz when there are no touches on screen. Check if there's any way to disable this feature.

AFAIK, OpenGL ES does not specify a standard for screen refresh rates, you will need a throttling function to ensure that your game runs/feels the same (i.e. at the same speed) despite differences in FPS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The best way to observe this phenomena is to use [systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html) with the "freq" tag enabled.  You probably need a rooted device, and you definitely need one on which systrace is enabled.

systrace will record changes in the clock frequency for various components.  It varies by device, but you can usually get the per-core CPU clocks and GPU memory rate.  You will likely see several of them drop significantly at the same time your frame rate drops.

The motivation for doing this is to reduce power requirements and extend battery life.  The assumption is that, while your finger is in contact with the screen, you're actively doing something and the device should be as responsive as possible.  After a brief period of time, the clocks will slow to a level appropriate for the current workload.  The heuristics that determine how long to wait before slowing, and how much to slow down, are tuned for each device.

(This has caused some people to create a thread that just sits and spins on multi-core devices as a way to artificially prop up the CPU clock rate.  Not recommended.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229196/high-performance-audio-cracking-prevent-a-cpu-core-from-downclocking/20248186#20248186).)

The bottom line is that this isn't a simple matter of adjusting thread priorities.  You have to choose between recognizing that the slowdown will happen and adapting to it (by making your game updates independent of frame rate), or figure out some way to fool the device into staying in a higher-power mode when you want smooth animation.

(For anyone who wants to play along at home: build a copy of [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) and start the "Record GL app" activity.  If you drag your finger around the screen all will be well, but if you leave it alone for a few seconds you may start to see the dropped-frame counter rising as the app falls behind.  Seen on Nexus 5, Nexus 7 (2013), and others.)